# Strange multithreaded problem on IIS 7

Tags: c#, multithreading, iis-7

The website has a .dll in its bin folder that has one method that is multithreaded.
Its a fairly fast process, (half a second) so timeout is not an issue.

On our development IIS 7, this runs without a hitch.  Same on all the programmers machines.  However, on the production IIS7, it fails to launch the parameterized thread
here are the code line:

```
ParameterizedThreadStart start = new ParameterizedThreadStart(queryDb);
Thread thrd = new Thread(start);
thrd.Start(ndb);
```

Its pretty standard stuff.  My question is, does anybody know of anything in IIS7 that would keep it from spawning a thread, like above

Comment: What kind of error are you getting on your production machine?

Comment: I'm not getting an error.  Thats the problem, theres nothing, at this point to go on.  I've checked the event logs and the WC3 logs.  Plus I log all my try catches to a database with a local text file as a fallback in case the db connection fails.  I'm not getting any errors any where. The thread just fails to launch.  But the exact same code on the dev machine and the programmers computers runs fine.  

fwiw, I compared the code on the dev and prod machine using .NET Reflector to make sure something weird hadn't happened there, its the same on both machines

Answer (score 0):

Potetnial reason: If you haven't correctly shutdown older threads and have 32 bit machine you soon will run out of address space to allocate stack for new threads.

Note: consider using thread pool (i.e. QueueWorkItem http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kbf0f1ct.aspx) to perform one off tasks. Or consider using asnchronous pages if processing is actually part of the page rendereing (instead of waiting for thread completition).

Comment: Its a 64 bit, Windows 7 machine.  I've thought about using the thread pool, but its not a fire and forget thread.  I have a wait handle that needs to be set, so the rest of the code can process.

Answer (score 0):

Another potential reason: the code requires full trust, which you have on your local testing, but not at the server. Do you use any security critical or unsafe code?

Comment: There is no unsafe or security critical code in this module.  Its all straight .net, simple database call, I put some logging in the method the thread calls, at the very beginning, before anything else was done, it never made it.  The method its calling is in the same class, so authentication shouldn't be an issue, it just simply does not launch the thread.